# Guaranteeing Invertibility with Banach Lemma

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, normed-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra

I'm trying to find an $\epsilon$ for which the Banach Lemma guarantees $I_n + ɛA_n$ is Invertible, where $A_n$ is a matrix of $1$'s, and $I_n$ is the identity matrix, and $n$ can be any dimension.

$ɛA_n$ results in a matrix of $ɛ$'s. When added to $I_n$, it becomes a matrix of $ɛ$'s with $e+1$'s on the main diagonal.

Using the Banach Lemma, the $$\|B\|$$ (using the infinity norm) for $I_n + ɛA_n$ must be $<$ 1.
With the resulting $B$ matrix, I found that $$\|B\| < 1$$ when the max of $$(n-1)ɛ / (ɛ+1) < 1$$

Is it possible to find a specific value for $ɛ$ that guarantees $I_n + ɛA_n$ is invertible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if $ɛ\Vert A_n\Vert =\Vert - ɛA_n\Vert =\Vert I_n-(I_n + ɛA_n)\Vert< 1 $ then $I_n + ɛA_n$ is invertible.

Comment: How do I determine an exact value for ɛ that makes the matrix In + ɛAn invertible?

Comment: $ɛ<\frac{1}{\Vert A_n\Vert }$